# Angular Rest Api con HttpClient

Tags: ajax, angular, typescript, rest, http

Estoy llamando a un servicio que ejecuta una función adentro.

```
this._itemService.searchProducts(product).subscribe(
   data => this.products = data
);
```

El problema esta en que la primera vez que se ejecuta no carga el valor en this.products. Simplemente queda como "undefined".
Al hacer click nuevamente en el Front si me carga correctamente todo..

Será algún problema async de typescript?

Muchas gracias

Comment: Deberías añadir más código, para que veamos cómo intentas usar el valor `products`

Comment: Utiliza `BehaviorSubject`: https://medium.com/@luukgruijs/understanding-rxjs-behaviorsubject-replaysubject-and-asyncsubject-8cc061f1cfc0